# Overriding already existing magento module adminhtml block

Tags: magento

Im trying to add one more custom field in Amasty shopby module. For that I need to override adminhtml form. I created module for that but that doesnt overriding the existing module. I have to override "Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General" class.
Here is my code.

Mycompany_Mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Amasty_Shopby />
                <Amasty_Base />
            </depends>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
_____________
______________
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                 <rewrite>        <filter_edit_tab_general>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General
                   </filter_edit_tab_general>
                 </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
 ____________
-________________
</config>
```

Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Filter\Edit\Tab\General.php

```
public class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General extends Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General
{
 _______________
___________
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to override right now is not Amasty block, but **adminhtml/filter_edit_tab_general**. So to rewrite **Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General** you need the following config:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <amshopby>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_filter_edit_tab_general>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Edit_Tab_General</adminhtml_filter_edit_tab_general>
            </rewrite>
        </amshopby>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Comment: Im trying to override one more form "Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Edit_Form" as you told. But couldn't override. In xml file under rewrite I added this line. <adminhtml_page_edit_form>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Edit_Form</adminhtml_page_edit_form>

Comment: The line itself looks fine. Did you put it inside <rewrite> or outside? It should be right below of your adminhtml_filter_edit_tab_general line. 
Also it depends on whether this Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Edit_Form is original block, or it overrides some core block. If it isn't original, then you must delete that rewrite from Amasty config.xml and then rewrite that core block in your extension.

Comment: Amasty_Shopby_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Edit_Form is a original one and I placed inside <rewrite>. But its not overriding.

Comment: Then unfortunately I have no idea what is wrong. Config seems fine to me, so it must be something else.

Comment: @AlexeiYerofeyev when overriding a block that is not extending a core block, I found doing the usual rewrite in the config but having the block be extended from the to-be-overridden block's parent worked fine (rather than the block itself) - so no need to modify the overridden module at all.